# Editing y axis range in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plot with exponential y axis range. I'm using multiplot command by inserting two images in one row. So due to this wide y axis range I'm loosing some space which I could use it to show my plots in a better way. I want basically something like this

[image]

How could i do this? I think for doing this I have do some math operations in the y axis range. Also what is the most convenient command to insert ( xE-10) at top left of the plot.

```
reset
set terminal epslatex size 16cm,18cm color colortext
set output new.tex
set key off
set format $%g$
set title "sinx"
set ylabel "[kNm]"
plot 1000000*sin(x)
```

This is not my exact code but  it looks similar to this. The plot I have presented is a part of the multiplot code and I use 7 input files with time series data of 300 seconds at a time step of 0.02. The point I want to edit the y axis range (use some mathtematical expressions) and also include the term ( xE-10 ) on the top of the plot something like this

[image]

Comment: For these kind of questions it really helps if your add some sample code, such that people can reproduce and easily test a solution. This leads to much more response.

Comment: I really want to present my code as it would help in solving the prorblem quickly. However, I use other software to run Gnuplot. So the way of presenting the Gnuplot code will be a bit different. Though I wanna present the code it will confusing if I do so as I pass the plot command inside a loops in a class that follows oops. Regarding the image I have posted above is an edited image in paint. I actually want the plot to look like that so I made some adjustments (like adding * E-10) in paint.

Comment: You can just create a simple gnuplot script that exactly replicates what you are actually seeing.

Comment: I have edited my post please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add the exponent with a `set label ...`. For instance, the following function takes large values within the given interval:

```
plot[0:50] exp(x)
```

[image]

We can place the "x 10^21" manually in the desired place after dividing the plotted quantity by it:

```
set label 1 "{/Symbol \264} 10^{21}" at graph 0,1.025 left
plot[0:50] exp(x)/1e21
```

[image]

You have to be careful with the exact placement of the exponent since it might lie outside the plotting area, in which case you should lower the top margin with `set tmargin ...`. Also, to use the "times" symbol, you need to pass the `enhanced` option to your terminal. With the epslatex terminal, you can use latex syntax: `$\times 10^{21}$`.